# Equivalence of categories of abelian presheaves reflects isomorphisms of rigid categories?

Tags: ct.category-theory

Recall that we call a category *rigid* if it contains no non-identity isomorphisms. Let $\mathbf{rig}$ denote the full 2-subcategory of $\mathbf{Cat}$ spanned by the small rigid categories. It is easy to see that a functor in $\mathbf{rig}$ is an equivalence of categories if and only if it is an isomorphism.

Then consider the 2-functor $\mathbf{Ab}(\cdot)=\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbf{Cat}}((\cdot)^{\operatorname{op}},\mathbf{Ab}):\mathbf{rig}^{\operatorname{op}}\to \mathbf{Cat}$ sending a small rigid category to its associated category of abelian presheaves.  Then if there is an equivalence of categories $\mathbf{Ab}(C) \simeq \mathbf{Ab}(D)$, where $C$ and $D$ are rigid, does this imply that $C$ is isomorphic to $D$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, this is false.  Let $C$ be the monoid $\lbrace 1,\ldots, 2^n\rbrace$ with $\max$ as the operation and let $D$ be the power set of $\lbrace 1,\ldots, n\rbrace$ with $\cup$ as the operation.  These are both join semilattices with identity of cardinality $2^n$.  The integral monoid rings of two finite join semilattices with identity of the same cardinality are isomorphic by Mobius inversion. Of course there are no isomorphisms other than identities here. More precisely, they are both isomorphic to a direct product of $2^n$ copies of $\mathbb Z$.  Of course for a monoid, abelian presheaves are the same as modules over the integral monoid ring.

See this [paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021980067800644) of Solomon for the proof the algebras are isomorphic.

**Added.**  Harry wanted an example where the categories are Cauchy complete.
The Cauchy completions of these monoids are not isomorphic and are rigid.  It is well known that for monoids $M$ and $N$ one has that $\mathbf{Set}^{M^{op}}\cong \mathbf{Set}^{N^{op}}$ if and only if there is an idempotent $e\in M$ with $MeM=M$ and $eMe\cong N$.  In particular, if $M$ is finite, then one must have $e=1$ and so $M\cong N$.  The two monoids I gave above are not isomorphic.

Comment: Great! I was hoping it was false, since it it were true, I'd have zero chance of extending the Dold-Kan theorem to a new context.

Comment: One other question, I guess. What if you require that the rigid categories are cauchy complete (i.e. all idempotents split)?

Comment: The Cauchy completions of the monoids I gave above are not isomorphic.  Finite monoids are determined up to isomorphism by Morita equivalence of presheaf toposes.  In general, two monoids $M$ and $N$ have equivalent classifying toposes iff there is an idempotent $e\in M$ such that $MeM=M$ and $eMe\cong N$. For finite monoids, this $e$ will have to be the identity.

Comment: Of course the Cauchy completions are rigid.

Comment: What if your categories are locally finite but have multiple objects?

Comment: The Cauchy completions of my monoids are finite with $2^n$ objects.

Comment: Great! This helps a great deal.  Thanks a lot.  Ultimately, I'm hoping that presheaves of abelian groups on Joyal's category $\Theta$ admit a Dold-Kan theorem (i.e. an equivalence of categories with connective chain complexes of abelian groups) that extends the Dold-Kan theorem on $\Delta$ (via the canonical embedding of $\Delta$ into $\Theta$).  Using some machinery of Steiner, such an equivalence should give an extension of Street's "orientalization" functor to all cellular sets (and therefore to all strict $\omega$-categories).  This would ultimately give a defn of a higher lax functor.

Comment: I am glad this helps. I must confess my category theory knowledge ends with toposes and 2/bi-categories.  I still haven't made it into the world of $\omega$-categories. One of these days...  In any event, my rule number 1 for category theory counter examples is look at finite monoids with trivial groups of units.

Comment: Well, strict $\omega$-categories are _much_ easier to handle than bicategories, since all coherence diagrams are trivial (no pentagons or anything nasty). The category $\Theta$ plays the role that $\Delta$ plays for $1$-categories, that is to say free objects on appropriate pushouts of source-target alternating diagrams of simple (globular) cells.  Steiner's theory then shows that these things are just finite chain complexes of free abelian groups equipped with bases. Moreover, "orientalization" is just the (normalized) embedding of $\Delta$ into chain complexes (with the obvious basis). 

Comment: So if the embedding of $\Delta$ into chain complexes can be extended to $\Theta$ and this extends to a Dold-Kan equivalence between abelian presheaves on $\Theta$ and chain complexes, this gives us a way to "freely assign orientations" to arbitrary commuting diagrams of shapes belonging to $\Theta$ in a strict $\omega$-category.  However, by a theorem of C. Berger, $\Theta$ is dense in strict omega-cats, so every $\omega$-cat $X$ is canonically the colimit of $\Theta\downarrow X$, which would extend the orientation procedure to al $\omega$-cats. Then morphisms out of that will be the lax ones.

Comment: That does sound interesting. I ran into some papers mentioning $\Theta$ once or twice.  I will look into it.